# Round-up and round-down R

Tags: r, rounding

It might seem silly but I have not been successful in trying to round my data as I wanted.
This is an example of my array:

`a<-c(-0.5:30,by=5)`

What I want is: for `min(a)` to **round-down** to the next number to multiples of 10 but the `max(a)` to **round-up**.

This case:

`min(a)=-0.5` and I want it round down to -10

`max(a)=29.5` and I want to round up (to 30 or 40).

I have spent time to think and search for it but have not found anything.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Regards,
Phuong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
a<- seq(from = -0.5, to = 30, by = 5)
```

For rounding up `max`:

```
roundUp <- function(x,to=10)
{
  to*(x%/%to + as.logical(x%%to))
}
roundUp(max(a))
```

For rounding down `min`:

```
roundDw <- function(x,to=-10)
{
  to*(x%/%to + as.logical(x%%to))
}
roundDw(min(a))
```

Comment: thanks for your help. This works for the case of -0.5 which will be rounded to -10. Maybe I wrongly described my question, but when I replaced -0.5 by -2.5 then it became 30 which I did not expect. My expectation is -10. But if min(a) is -12 then I expect -20.

Comment: what is the expected range of your numbers? will you have any number in your array?

Comment: Sorry for late reply as I was testing the codes. They are working greatly. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `round_any` from `plyr`.

```
library(plyr)

a <- seq(-0.5, 30, by = 5) 

round_any(min(a), 10, f = floor)
## -10  

round_any(max(a), 10, f = ceiling)
##  30
```